# How to achieve data size reduction via numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

My following code generates a matrix-like that contains values in their binary representation:

```
import sys
import random

Arr = list(set([random.randint(0, 2 ** 8) for i in range(10)]))
Arr = [('{0:08b}').format(i) for i in Arr]
Arr = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(i))) for i in Arr])
print Arr
print "dtype= %d , size of Arr is (%d) bytes \n" % (Arr.itemsize, sys.getsizeof(Arr))
```

The result is:

`dtype= 8 , size of Arr is (752) bytes`

As you can see, seems like `Numpy`picked up `8` byte for each binary digit which gives total size of `Arr = 752 bytes`. However, my code should generate a matrix of 10 million values from the range `random.randint(0, 2 ** 128)`. To reduce the total size, a friend of mine suggested me to use `dtype=np.int8` as `np.asarray([list(map(int, list(i))) for i in Arr], dtype=np.int8)`. Once applied, the result became:

`dtype= 1 , size of Arr is (192) bytes`

A huge reducion from `752` to `192`byte. As both of us are new in Python programming, is this a correct approach of size reduction?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `int8`, since you only have positive numbers, you could use an unsigned int: `np.uint8()`. But I don't understand why you would store it like this, you're storing each *bit* of a number with a *byte*. Storing the *actual number* and then converting it just-in-time when you need it (if you're actually doing something with the binary values) seems like it would be far more memory efficient.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for your response. The reason why I am converting each integer number into binary representation is that my algorithm that I use in my project requires binary representation of each integer. Since binary, I thought to use `int8` ( or `uint8` as you suggested) to store each binary digit! I am not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: Idk if it's a good idea, it would depend on the function IMO. Each bit will be represented as a byte, which is a huge memory waste. It's 8 times the storage! If you could convert each value as it's used, that would be best. BUT---if you *did* want to do it anyways, then you can pack the binary values into `uint8` values with [`np.packbits()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) and unpack them with [`np.unpackbits()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html).